# not able to add foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql

i have three table user, roles and user_roles and when i try to add user_id to users(id) and roles_id to roles(id).  it not showing from relation view in phpmyadmin and when i try to add through sql query it shows error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the table definitions as text to the question. and review the conditions required to create an FK here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html